# Tikz array indexing as node text value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I would like to use numbers stored in an array as node text values, but this doesn't work on my side:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0,...,5} {
            \node (a\x) at (\x*1.75,0) [regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw] {\xi};
        }
        \def\firstSums{{3, 7, 11}}
        \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0, 2, 4} {
            \node (b\x) at (\x*1.75,-1.75) [circle,draw] {\firstSums[\xi - 1]};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Instead of getting circles with 3, 7 and 11 as text in them I get circles which have `3,7,11[1-1]`, `3,7,11[2-1]`, `3,7,11[3-1]` as text in them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By use of the `\pgfmathsetmacro` in the loop and relative positioning of nodes in the second row:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm, 
C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.7em,inner sep=0pt}
                        ]
\foreach \x [count=\i]in {0,...,5}
{
\node (a\i) [draw] at (1.2*\x,0)  {\i};
\ifodd \x\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(2*\i+1)}
\node[C, below of=a\i] {\j};
\fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to reference the array's element by index, you need to parse the expression by tikz/pgf engine by doing

```
\pgfmathparse{\firstSums[\xi - 1]}
```

However this won't print the result, so you need an extra `\pgfmathresult`, so that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0,...,5} {
        \node (a\x) at (\x*1.75,0) [regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw] {\xi};
    }
    \def\firstSums{{3, 7, 11}}
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0, 2, 4} {
        \node (b\x) at (\x*1.75,-1.75) [circle,draw] {\pgfmathparse{\firstSums[\xi - 1]}\pgfmathresult};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, there is an `eveluate` syntax inside `foreach`. I personally recommend using this approach that allows to make the code shorter by avoiding long macros like `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathresult`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0,...,5} {
        \node (a\x) at (\x*1.75,0) [regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw] {\xi};
    }
    \def\firstSums{{3, 7, 11}}
    \foreach \x [count=\xi, evaluate={\elem=\firstSums[\xi - 1]}] in {0, 2, 4} {
        \node (b\x) at (\x*1.75,-1.75) [circle,draw] {\elem};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]